# Javascript Minimax Function Exceedingly Slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, tic-tac-toe, minimax

After initiating the tic-tac-toe AI move (it's currently written only to assess if miniMax can successfully run), it takes about 1 - 1.5 minutes to complete in firefox or chrome. Other tic-tac-toe game's minimax functions run on my computer in a fraction of the time.
Logging output has not led closer to the solution. Have verified that all terminal states return a score. Is there an obvious error here?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MadisonMaxM/pen/EQeLEj?editors=0010)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var state = {
  status: "inProgress",
  turn: "human", //can be human or AI
  game: 1,

turnSwitch: function() {
  if (this.turn == "human") {
    return (this.turn = "AI");
  } else if (this.turn == "AI") {
    return (this.turn = "human");
    }
  }
};

//AI will use minimx algorithm to determine best possible move
function player(name, symbol) {
  this.name = name;
  this.symbol = symbol;
}

var human = new player("human", "X");
var AI = new player("AI", "O");

var board = {
    board: [],

    createBoard: function() {
      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        this.board.push(i);
      }
      return this.board;
    },

    resetBoard: function() {
      this.board = [];
      createBoard();
    },

    //checks board for terminal state
    terminalTest: function() {
      for (let i = 0; i < 7; i += 3) {
        if (
          this.board[i] == this.board[i + 1] &&
          this.board[i] == this.board[i + 2]
        ) {
          if (typeof this.board[i] !== "number") {
            return this.board[i];
          }
        }
      }

      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (
          this.board[j] == this.board[j + 3] &&
          this.board[j] == this.board[j + 6]
        ) {
          if (typeof this.board[j] !== "number") {
            return this.board[j];
          }
        }
      }
      if (
        (this.board[0] == this.board[4] && this.board[0] == this.board[8]) ||
        (this.board[2] == this.board[4] && this.board[2] == this.board[6])
      ) {
        if (typeof this.board[4] !== "number") {
          return this.board[4];
        }
      }
    },

    //checks for possible moves
    findEmptyIndicies: function() {
      return this.board.filter(a => typeof a == "number");
    }
  };



function miniMax(boardCurrent, player) {
    //store all possible moves
    var availableMoves = boardCurrent.findEmptyIndicies();
    console.log("available moves length " + availableMoves.length);

    //if terminal state, return score
    var terminalCheck = boardCurrent.terminalTest();

    if (terminalCheck === "X") {
      //console.log(boardCurrent.board + " X wins score: -10")
      return human.symbol == "X" ? { score: -10 } : { score: 10 };
    } else if (terminalCheck === "O") {
      //console.log(boardCurrent.board + " ) wins score: 10")
      return human.symbol == "X" ? { score: 10 } : { score: -10 };
    } else if (availableMoves.length === 0) {
      console.log("availmoves length 0 " + availableMoves.length);
      //console.log(boardCurrent.board + " score: 0")
      return { score: 0 };
    }
    //array to store objects containing index and score through each iteration of available moves
    var movesArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < availableMoves.length; i++) {
      //create object to store return score from each index branch
      var move = {};

      move.index = boardCurrent.board[availableMoves[i]];

      boardCurrent.board[availableMoves[i]] = player.symbol;

      //returned score from leaf node if conditionials at top of function are met

      if (player.name == "AI") {
        var miniMaxReturn = miniMax(boardCurrent, human);
        move.score = miniMaxReturn.score;
        console.log("move score " + move.score);
      } else {
        var miniMaxReturn = miniMax(boardCurrent, AI);
        move.score = miniMaxReturn.score;
        console.log("move score " + move.score);
      }

      boardCurrent.board[availableMoves[i]] = move.index;

      movesArray.push(move);
    }
    var bestMove;
    console.log("moves array length " + movesArray.length);
    if (player.name === "AI") {
      let bestScore = -1000;
      for (let i = 0; i < movesArray.length; i++) {
        if (movesArray[i].score > bestScore) {
          bestScore = movesArray[i].score;

          bestMove = i;
        }
      }
    } else if (player.name === "human") {
      let bestScore = 1000;
      for (let i = 0; i < movesArray.length; i++) {
        if (movesArray[i].score < bestScore) {
          bestScore = movesArray[i].score;
          bestMove = i;
        }
      }
    }

    return movesArray[bestMove];
  }



/**function AIMove() {
    console.log("ai move initiated");
    var AIPosition = miniMax(board, AI);
    //var index = AIposition.index;
    //console.log(AIposition);
    //$("#" + index).html(AI.symbol);
  }**/

  $(".cell").click(displayMove);

  function displayMove() {
    if (state.turn == "human") $(this).html(human.symbol);

    board.board[this.id] = human.symbol;

    state.turn = "AI";
    miniMax(board, AI);
    //AIMove();
    console.log("AI move complete");
  }

  $(".cell").click(displayMove);

  //on window load create board
  board.createBoard();

});
```

Comment: That's a huge chunk of code for us to try and puzzle through. Can you boil that down to a more *minimal* example?

Comment: Youre caught in a loop. If you open the console on that codepen and click on a square it just keeps running.

Comment: @Craicerjack The main issue is that the jquery click event was being triggered in dupcliate, which is why it would take 90 seconds to complete in Chrome. It still seemed slow upon fixing the error- converted the board object to stand alone functions and variables- less information to pass through each recursion. Thanks for taking a look